# Not able to set command line arguments in gradle's JavaExec task

Tags: java, gradle

Not able to set command line arguments while configuring subprojects' task.

```
task doStuff {
    def executable_task = project(':SubProject1').getTasksByName('run',true)
    println executable_task.name
    println executable_task.args
    executable_task.args('xyz')
}
```

This error message is being showed:

> What went wrong:
>   A problem occurred evaluating root project 'MainProject'.
>   No signature of method: java.util.HashSet.args() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [xyz]
>     Possible solutions: any(), grep(), grep(), add(java.lang.Object), add(java.lang.Object), is(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score -1):

The method [Project.getTasksByName()](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#getTasksByName(java.lang.String,%20boolean)) returns a `Set` of `Task` instances. You will need to assign the field to each element in the `Set`.

```
task doStuff {
    doLast {
        Set<Task> executableTasks = project(':SubProject1').getTasksByName('run', true)
        executableTasks.each {
            it.args 'xyz'
        }
    }
}
```

BTW: I don't understand why you need to set arguments for a task in a different project. Couldn't you just set it in the subproject `:SubProject1` that defines the task? I'd actually set the task properties within `:SubProject1` with a configuration rule:

```
tasks.withType(JavaExec).matching { it.name == 'run' }.each { it.args 'xyz' }
```

Comment: I do not want to get the fields values, I want to update them. I am already able to get the value successfully.

Comment: Updated the code. BTW: There's no method `args` on the [Task API](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html).

Comment: still not able to set the value, can you provide me a working example

Comment: I updated the example. Ignore my previous comment. I didn't realize that the task was of type `JavaExec`.